# Relacionamento em Laravel/Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com um problema. Preciso retornar os valores de um relacionamento, porém, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$fileServico
```

O meu código:

FileClass.php

```
public function fileServico(){
    return $this->hasMany('File');
}
```

FileServico.php

```
public function file(){
    return $this->belongsTo('File');
}
```

Pode ter vários FileServico para um FileClass.
Como estou chamando:

ReservaController.php

```
public function getIndex(){
    return View::make('home')->with('file',FileClass::all()->fileServico);
}
```

Comment: Ewerton Melo, coloque na sua questão  as duas tabelas e as classes em completo por favor! de cara o seu relacionamento ta errado, mas, como eu não sei o nome das suas `class` fica dificil colocar a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Isso

```
FileClass::all()->fileServico
```

Não funciona. No caso para pegar os `fileServico` de cada `FileClass`, teria que ser em uma iteração:

```
foreach( FileClass::all() as $item ){
    var_dump( $item->fileservico );
}
```